# how to retrieve coordinates of a Place by query string | google-maps angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

In my Angular 15 application I have imported `@angular/google-maps` version 15.2.9.

I have a custom typeahead and I managed to use `Places API` to retrieve suggestions with the following code:
**map.service**

```
if (!input) return of({ predictions: [] });
const AutocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
const req: AutocompletionRequest = {
    input,
};
return from(AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(req));
```

My typeahead emits an event when the user click on a suggestion, and I want to get the position of the selected suggestion.
I tried the following:
**map.service**

```
const req: FindPlaceFromQueryRequest = {
    fields: ['geometry'],
    query,
};
const place = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map).findPlaceFromQuery(req);
```

Map is always undefined so I don't get any results. I'm setting map with this code:
**map.component**

```
<google-map #map (mapInitialized)="onMapInitialized($event)"></google-map>
```

```
@ViewChild('map', { static: false }) private map!: GoogleMap;
onMapInitialized(event: unknown) {
    this.map = event as GoogleMap;
    if (this.map.googleMap) this.mapService.map = this.map.googleMap
}
```

I don't know if `findPlaceFromQuery` is the right function, my ultimate goal is to center the map to the new coordinates.
I also would prefer avoid using a function that requires `Map`, so I don't have to export it from the component. I just need a way to get coordinates of a `Place` based on a `query: string` input

**UPDATE**
I noticed the problem is that the package [initializes the `map.googleMap` object asynchronously](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/google-maps/google-map/google-map.ts#L310-L314), so it is not directly available at the execution of `onMapInitialized`.
I still don't know how to access when it is initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Obtaining the `map` within `onMapInitialized` is one thing and I suppose others can help you out with that.

I'd only point out that you actually **don't need the a Google map instance to use the Places Service**!

Extracted from [my handbook](https://gmapsbook.com/learn-google-maps/bulletproof-address-autocomplete-3e1040630f5e426f891d6bfd12bd73f8#bb9fc8997a9b4cc2b358f41815c19ad5):

> The `new google.maps.places.PlacesService` constructor requires you to provide a `HTMLDivElement` or a `google.maps.Map` instance. While including the map container is often advantageous, you can pass in an arbitrary (and even a hidden) HTML element — provided that you render the [attributions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/policies#logo) elsewhere programmatically.

The only remaining thing to do is make sure that `req` — the argument you pass onto [`findPlaceFromQuery`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.findPlaceFromQuery) — conforms to the [`FindPlaceFromQueryRequest` interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#FindPlaceFromQueryRequest).

Comment: It seems a bit hacky to pass a hidden HTML element, I would prefer either passing the Map or using another method, if exists, that doesn't require any HTML element